# Downscale bitmap screenshot of the screen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap

I have a piece of code here which takes a "screenshot" of the display with `HDC` (with a high resolution aware program):

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

HBITMAP hbDesktop = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, width, height);

SelectObject(hDest, hbDesktop);
BitBlt(hDest, 0,0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Problem is, on higher resolutions displays such as mine (2736x1824), the bitmap image is very large coming in at around 14MB; and I certainly do not need that high of a resolution and would like to downscale it to a more reasonable size of around 1MB if possible as I want to send it over a TCP connection. I am very new to HDC so cut me some slack. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said what you want to do with the bitmap. Instead of `BitBlt` you can use `StretchBlt` to stretch the capture to a smaller bitmap, if that's what you want. Or if you're talking about disk space, writing the bitmap as a JPG or PNG would be a way to reduce its size.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I actually want to send it over a TCP connection, hence why the 14MB is a problem.

Comment: @EpicSpeedy how are you going to *use* the bitmap on the other side of the TCP connection? How the image is *transmitted* is separate from how it will be *used*. You can always compress the TCP transmission without changing the bitmap data itself, for instance.

Comment: @JonathanPotter On the other side the bitmap will go through some processing including being written to the disk. And indeed, TCP compression could help and I'll look into that. However, it would be better to also render the bitmap in a lower resolution since it's a lot less computational burden and better transmission savings, if that's possible at least. That kind of resolution I mentioned in my question is very overkill for a screenshot and even halving that will bring massive savings.

Comment: There cannot ever be too much resolution when post-processing an image. Although, all of this reads like premature optimization. An attempt at fixing problems without evidence that those problems actually exist.

Comment: @IInspectable Of course having the whole image would be great but it's not feasible. I have took Jonathan's suggestion on board with compression, and so I used zlib to compress the entire bitmap and sent it across. This lowered the size to about 300KB which can easily be sent across a network, problem is another problem was introduced which is the overhead of compression and decompression. I have benchmarked everything before this and so this is why I want to reduce the resolution of the screenshot. I do not need 2736x1824 with 24-bit depth.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use [StretchBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) to resize the bitmap.

Refer to the Doc:[Scaling an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/scaling-an-image)